# Shortcut key to Toggle Results Pane SQL Editor Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2012, I'm trying to use Ctrl+R and it is not hiding results pane in SQL Editor window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Ctrl+D, R`.

Do notice that it is **NOT** `Ctrl+D, Ctrl+R`, i.e. you will have to lift your finger from `Ctrl` key when you press `R`

[image: Tools > Environment > Keyboard]

Comment: Good answer. As simple as this answer is, it could be improved changing "not Ctrl+D, Ctrl+R" to "<b>NOT</b> Ctrl+D, Ctrl+R".  My eyes immediately went to the larger highlighted keyboard shortcut and when it didn't work I almost gave up.  I found the right shortcut by trying some variations myself, only to look back at your answer to see that's what you had all along.  :P

Comment: FYI, in the latest VS 2017, this no longer works because they've added Ctrl+D as a global shortcut for "Duplicate Line".  So, now this is apparently impossible by default.  :-(

Comment: @Sean yes, you may want to assign a different shortcut key to it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard / General.

[image]